# How to pass bound symbols to functions in elisp?

Tags: macros, lisp, elisp

I am trying to do the following: separate a function that gets values from some user input from the function that uses it.

I have tried the following code for the proof of concept initially (that worked):

```
(defun initialiser (bindings)
  (cl-loop for (var) in bindings do
           (set var (read-from-minibuffer "Input value: "))))
```

That i have tested with:

```
(let ((name))
  (initialiser '((name)))
  (message "name is %S" name))
```

The idea was to pass bindings to the function that handles input in the form like `((name "Name") (address "Post address") (code "County code"))` or something similar, and in there assign the input.

After testing above i have come up with the following macro to do things:

```
(defmacro initialise-and-execute (bindings initialiser &rest callback-actions)
  (let ((unwrapped-bindings (map 'list (lambda (binding) (car binding)) bindings)))
    `(let ,unwrapped-bindings
       (,initialiser (quote ,bindings)
                     (lambda () ,@callback-actions)))))
```

However, in the "real" scenario the assignments must happen in callbacks, like:

```
(defun initialiser(bindings)
  (cl-loop for (var) in bindings collect
           (lambda () (set var (read-from-minibuffer "Input value: ")))
           into callbacks
           return callbacks))
```

This fails to work. Code i have used to test was:

```
(defvar callbacks nil)
(let ((name))
  (setq callbacks (initialiser '((name)))))
(funcall (car callbacks))
```

Edit: changed the code the following way:

```
(defmacro initialise-and-execute (bindings initialiser &rest callback-actions)
  (let ((unwrapped-bindings (map 'list (lambda (binding) (car binding)) bindings)))
    `(lexical-let ,unwrapped-bindings
       (,initialiser
        (quote ,(map 'list
                     (lambda (binding) (list (cadr binding)
                                             `(lambda (val) (setq ,(car binding) val))))
                     bindings))
        (lambda () ,@callback-actions)))))
```

What it must do: generate number of lambdas that share the same lexical environment - one that uses captured variables and the rest that modify them.

However, what i get is, regrettably, something else. Symbols used in `callback-actions` do not resolve into the values set.

For completeness, here is how i tested it:

```
(defun init-values (bindings callback)
  (loop for (desc setter) in bindings
        for idx = 0 then (incf idx)
        do (print (format "Setting %s" desc))
        (funcall setter idx))
  (funcall callback))

(initialise-and-execute
                 ((name "Name")
                  (surname "Surname"))
               init-values
               (message "name is %S" name))
```

Here, lambdas were not generated in a `loop` and values in the context of a lexical binding were assigned with `setq`.

Comment: This is rather unclear. Simply passing the symbols should trivially work. Can you provide a [mre] without the complex macro, with just some bound but undefined symbol and a demonstration of how something like `(set symbol value)` does not work like you expected? However, I guess you are barking up the wrong tree really.

Comment: Added a reproductible example

Comment: If you want to pass some association between symbols and values to something it is almost always better to pass an alist or a hashtable or something like that.  `set` is almost never what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, i have been able to do it. The key was realising that `lexical-let` apparently had some restrictions on how the lambda should be placed for them to have the same closure context. After i have managed to generate set of closures that referred to the same variables, the rest was easy.

Here is the final code:

```
(defmacro make-lamba-set (bindings &rest callback-actions)
  "Make set of closures with shared context
BINDINGS are a list of form (SYMBOL NAME), where SYMBOL is not defined yet
CALLBACK-ACTIONS are forms that use symbols from bindings
Return created captures a as a list of forms:
(do-callback-actions (set-symbol NAME) ...)"
  (let ((unwrapped-bindings (map 'list
                                 (lambda (binding)
                                   (car binding))
                                 bindings)))
    `(lexical-let ,unwrapped-bindings
       (list (lambda () ,@callback-actions)
             ,@(map 'list
                    (lambda (binding)
                      `(list
                         (lambda (val)
                           (setq ,(car binding) val))
                         ,(cadr binding)))
                    bindings)))))

(defmacro initialise-and-execute (bindings initialiser &rest callback-actions)
  "BINGINGS have form of ((BINDING-SYMBOL PROMPT) ...)
   INITIALISER somehow assigns values to all of BINDING-SYMBOL
   then it calls CALLBACK-ACTIONS with values of BINDING-SYMBOL set"
  `(let ((closure-parts (make-lamba-set ,bindings ,@callback-actions)))
    (,initialiser (cdr closure-parts)
                  (car closure-parts))))
```

Here is how i tested it:

```
(defun init-values (bindings callback)
  (loop for (setter desc) in bindings
        for idx = 0 then (incf idx)
        do (message "Setting %s" desc)
           (funcall setter idx))
  (funcall callback))

(initialise-and-execute ((name "Name")
                         (surname "Surname"))
                        init-values
                        (insert (format "Name is %S and surname is %S"
                                        name
                                        surname)))
```

That gave me expected output of:

> Name is 0 and surname is 1

Answer (score 1):

To set the function value, use `fset`, not `set`.

```
(defun initialiser(bindings)
  (cl-loop for (var) in bindings collect
           (lambda () (fset var (read-from-minibuffer "Input value: ")))
           into callbacks
           return callbacks))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are possible issues:

- in a LOOP the VAR is possibly assigned on each iteration, not bound (that's in Common Lisp). so your callbacks set all the same VAR value.
- in a lexical bound Lisp (new in GNU Emacs Lisp) one **can't** set the variable values with SET

Examples:

```
ELISP> (mapcar #'funcall
               (cl-loop for i in '(1 2 3 4)
                        collect (lambda () i)))
(4 4 4 4)
```

all closures have the same value of i

```
ELISP> (let ((a 'foobar))
         (set 'a 42)
         a)
foobar
```

SET had no effect on the local variable

Comment: Both those things seems like the problems i have. However, it does not seem like trying to change around them helps. I will add the changed code to the question

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp I might write something like:

```
(defun initializer (bindings)
  (loop for (what setter) in bindings
        for new-value = (progn
                          (format t "Enter ~a: "  what)
                          (finish-output)
                          (read-line))
        do (funcall setter new-value)))


(defmacro call-with-bindings (name-sym-list fn)
  (let ((value-sym (gensym "v"))) 
    `(,fn
      (list ,@(loop for (name sym) in name-sym-list
                    collect `(list ,name ,`(lambda (,value-sym)
                                             (setf ,sym ,value-sym))))))))




CL-USER > (let (name age)
            (call-with-bindings  (("name" name) ("age" age))
                                 initializer)
            (format t "name is ~S~%" name)
            (values name age))
Enter name: Lara
Enter age: 42
name is "Lara"
"Lara"
"42"
```

Where we can look at the macro expansion:

```
CL-USER > (pprint (macroexpand-1
                   '(call-with-bindings  (("name" name) ("age" age))
                                         initializer)))

(INITIALIZER (LIST (LIST "name"
                         (LAMBDA (#:|v1669|)
                           (SETF NAME #:|v1669|)))
                   (LIST "age"
                         (LAMBDA (#:|v1669|)
                           (SETF AGE #:|v1669|)))))
```